/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpackage_name
I am new to ROS2 (Foxy) and CMake. I have a ROS2 package called senso_gui_control, that is dependent on another package in my workspace (senso_client).
When trying to run colcon build, I get the following error:
--- stderr: senso_gui_control                             
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsenso_client
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsenso_client
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/senso_gui_control_node.dir/build.make:461: senso_gui_control_node] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:107: CMakeFiles/senso_gui_control_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< senso_gui_control [1.41s, exited with code 2]

My CMakeLists.txt (senso_gui_control) looks like this:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(senso_gui_control)

if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra)
endif()

# find packages
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(ethercat_manager REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(senso_joint_state_publisher REQUIRED)
find_package(rmw_implementation REQUIRED)
find_package(soem_ros2 REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)  
find_package(senso_client REQUIRED)  
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_runtime REQUIRED)
find_package(senso_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(cap_grant_ld REQUIRED)

include_directories(include ${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${ament_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(senso_gui_control_node src/senso_gui_control_node.cpp src/senso_gui_control.cpp) 
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} /dev/null)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} cap_grant_ld::libcap_grant_ld)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)

target_link_directories(senso_gui_control_node
PRIVATE
     include
     ${dependencies_INCLUDE_DIRS}
     )
ament_target_dependencies(senso_gui_control_node
     rclcpp
     rmw_implementation
     std_msgs
     rosidl_default_generators
     ethercat_manager
     senso_joint_state_publisher
     soem_ros2
     rosidl_default_runtime
     senso_msgs
     senso_client
     )

target_link_directories(senso_gui_control_node PUBLIC senso_client)   
target_link_libraries(senso_gui_control_node ${rclcpp_LIBRARIES} senso_client)
target_link_libraries(senso_gui_control_node
 ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.a
 install/ethercat_manager/lib/libethercat_manager.so
 install/soem_ros2/lib/libsoem.a
)




install(TARGETS senso_gui_control_node
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)
install(DIRECTORY
launch config
DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}
)


set(PROJECT_CAPS "cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin,cap_sys_nice=ep")
configure_file(postinst.bash.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/postinst.bash @ONLY NEWLINE_STYLE UNIX)

install(
  PROGRAMS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/postinst.bash
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
  RENAME postinst
)
ament_package()

As you can see, I am trying to link senso_gui_control with senso_client, that leads to the error, but I am quite stuck with this (not much experience). I would appreciate any help!
